# What is the name of this Snow White cartoon?

Tags: story-identification, anime

There was this ***Snow White*** cartoon tv show which I watched in the us 2003-2006 (may have been reruns)
The details I remember apart from the regular 7 dwarves, Prince Charming, magic mirror and evil stepmother.

There's an episode where the dwarves use 7 ribbons in the forest to make some kind of magic barrier that prevents the magic mirror from detecting Snow White. Then in a later episode one of the ribbons gets cut and the Queen starts chasing her again

Snow White and Charming go to this alternate reality place. A rainbow marks the place where they entered. There's a scene where the two of them see rainbow in different places because they entered that realm in different places.

Also the Queen transforms into a dragon or something like that... let's just say Charming fights a dragon.

Answer (score 5):

It's [The Legend of Snow White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Snow_White) from Mondo tv

> Queen Chrystal tried to take the life of Snow White several times: once by a poisoned ribbon, another time with an enchanted comb, times at which the dwarfs saved her with help from their Book of Knowledge. But during the Queen's last attempt, she finally succeeds to put her in an enchanted sleep - by means of a poisoned apple - in order to take over her body, for hers is aging rapidly due to use of sorcery against a pure soul.